# How to backup rpm dependencies downloaded by yum while installing?

Tags: centos, rpm, yum

I need to install git on a machine which doesn't have internet connection. I am wondering if there is any option to ask yum to keep a backup of rpm and dependencies it downloads.

OS: CENTOS

Comment: `yumdownloader --resolve`?

Answer (score 0):

1.Downloadonly plugin for yum

Install the package including "downloadonly" plugin:
    Raw
   (RHEL5)

```
# yum install yum-downloadonly
```

(RHEL6)

```
# yum install yum-plugin-downloadonly
```

2. Run yum command with "--downloadonly" option as follows:

   *yum install --downloadonly --downloaddir=**directory** **package***
3. Confirm the RPM files are available in the specified download directory.

[source](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/10154)